# Any psychological self-test questionnaire to measure philosophical stances?

Tags: belief, philosophy-of-culture, measurement, demographics

Possible cross-domain duplicate: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/17532/are-there-any-tests-for-ones-belief-or-philosophy

There are various multiple-choice questions across internet, that roughly give an estimated measurement on your personality type, your political stance, your mental health condition etc. Some even attempt to calculate likelihood of having a  neurological differences such as dyslexia, ADHD and autism-spectrum through learning patterns and interests. There are even tests for career choices.  The tests range from purely unscientific/astrology or divination based to approved tests based on psychodiagnostic criteria. Not going to judge clinical validity of these tests.

But is there any such test for multiple dimension of philosophical standpoints?

For example, I have felt like (but I do not have any measurement for)

- I have mostly a dualist perception, with slightly more convinced towards idealism than physicalism.
- My religious position is in between Agnostic to Theist, with a tendency towards animism. I have a tendency to tolerate, accept and embrace all the pluralistic views on religions, although I have a personal liking towards polytheistic and idolatrous religions, and their artistic and cultural values.
- My political position is more towards equality and equity, and not bowing head to Authority, rather believes that respect is something to earn. Still it does not fit into typical western "Left" or "right" binary. Such as during a deficiency (such as during a draught or famine or inflation) I may choose spirituality and prayer as a coping mechanism than immediately accusing the political Authority as good or bad. I would reduce my financial expectations from society and government; and will focus more on what I can do best in this situation to support myself and other people. You may call it a "Low living", you may call it "gratitude" but I have not seen this being discussed in either left or right leaning arguments.
- My believe towards goal of life is to get peace and solace, to "feel" more senses through art forms, getting close to nature.

These are some examples of few of my philosophical stances, and they continuously change/ evolve/ transform at a slow rate, depending upon life situation, maturity, reading history, listening to people and culture, etc.

Now my question is, is there any available questionnaries or scale to measure these philosophical stances? Are they available online?

Comment: Hello @community kindly help me fix, this question has already a duplicate here https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/17532/are-there-any-tests-for-ones-belief-or-philosophy

Answer (score 2):

Update: there is a good one: [Clearthinking Org](https://programs.clearerthinking.org/philosophical_beliefs.html?)  which gave a profile like this:

1. Abstract objects: Platonist
2. Aesthetic beauty: Aesthetic subjectivist
3. External world: External world skeptic
4. Free will: Libertarian
5. God: Theist
6. Knowledge claims: Contextualist
7. Law of Nature: Humean
8. Meta ethics: Moral Anti-realist
9. Mind: Anti-physicalist
10. Moral judgement: Non-cognitivist
11. Newcomb's problem: Two boxer
12. Normative ethics: Deontologist
13. Politics: Communitarian
14. Science: Scientific anti-realist
15. Teletransporter: Leads to death
16. Truth: Correspondence truth
17. Zombies: Conceivable and possible

There is a PHC (philosophy health check) [tension score](https://www.philosophyexperiments.com/health/Default3.aspx)  that figures out conflicting beliefs or cognitive dissonance where it spotted at least in 4 areas of human lives that I am simulltaneously holding but they are inconsistent or contradictory. This includes Absoluteness of truth, Absoluteness of morality,  Freedom to self-pleasure, and Art subjectivity.

I found several websites.

According to [Belief Net](https://www.beliefnet.com/entertainment/quizzes/beliefomatic.aspx), My stances are close to Taoism

According to this [proprofs quiz](https://www.proprofs.com/quiz-school/story.php?title=what-religion-are-you) My beliefs match with Hinduism

The [Pew Research Centre](https://www.pewresearch.org/religion/interactives/how-the-religious-typologies-compare/?issue=race-ethnicity)'s quiz identifies me as a "Sunday Stallwort" (Most radically religious), although in several questions I have voted that I am not active with church, I prefer to pray (or worship) alone on my home, I don't believe in hell, and " I DO NOT believe in God as described in the Bible, but I do believe there is some other higher power or spiritual force in the universe". Where  their graphs very clearly shows I am highly deviating from general public in these beliefs. I guess this inaccuracy is because the Pew research centre's quiz forces to vote within either christian beliefs and atheistic beliefs.

According to [big five personality traits](https://www.truity.com/test-results/bigfive/18708/54183595) I score very high to openness, moderate to high in agreeableness, conscientiousness and neuroticism and very low in Extroversion. The personality test recognizes me as Empathic idealist (96%) and practical caretaker (as 46%)

[The Political Compass](https://www.politicalcompass.org/analysis2?ec=-7.0&soc=-4.97) places me in the quadrant for somewhat left and liberal.
[image: Quadrant]

Comment: Which conclusions do you draw from making these different tests? Are there any results concerning your philosophical(!) - not religious or political - stance?

Comment: This is only a partial answer. None of the tests are very useful in figuring out the dimensions of philosophical concepts. One thing is clear that somebody can be religious and libertarian at the same time, or how these values or basis of ethics sometime overlap.

Comment: @JoWehler if you find a better test (or tests) please post that.

Comment: @JoWehler Please check the updates

Comment: The Political Compass is not considered a serious toolkit by political scholars

Comment: @AgnishomChattopadhyay I don't have a better toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

I have entered your self-description into ChatGPT and obtained a classification according to your four criteria. The classification is nearly echoing your own words, but it adds a summary in three lines. Hence ChatGPT does not provide a quantitative classification. Aside: This shows the current limits of ChatGPT.

If you ask for a quantitative classification with respect to a well-defined number of dimensions and a numerical scale on each dimension, I do not know about such assessment of the *philosophical* stance of a person.

But there exists such tests for *personality*, e.g. on the basis of the "five-factor model of personality". For an introduction see [Big_Five_personality_traits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Five_personality_traits).

Comment: Does it cover ones' philosophical stance?

Comment: @Citizen and Society The five factor model does not(!) cover the philosophical stance, see the link from my answer.

Comment: I have found several different tests. I would write an answer, thank you